# Two input cells equal to each other

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to create two input cells that are equal to each other without VBA code eg. A1 = A5 and A5 = A1. So when I change the value of A1 it affects A5 and change in A5 makes A1 change too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not. It will require VBA.

A cell can have a formula or it can have a user supplied value but not both.

The only way is VBA.

You can have a third cell, say B1.  Then have the user change B1 and equate A1 and A5 to B1:

```
=B1
```

Then the user only needs to change one cell and the others will update.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking it is possible, if the sheet is set to use iterative calculation, with using `=B1` in A5 and `=A5` in B1. However entering data in either cell will overwrite the formula, so would only work the one time.